# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A: sslv3 alert certificate revoked

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error from apns, using ruby_on_rails.

Any suggestion, where is the problem app or ruby server?

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728436/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-c) may be help you

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem with the App. Better you use the updated RubyGems version.

This article may help you more to understand this issue - https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88